# HDD makes high-pitched noise in Windows, but it is silent in Ubuntu!

Tags: windows, hard-drive, noise

I was just wondering what's different about Ubuntu that makes my HDD work more silently than in Windows. In Windows my hard disk makes a very audible high-pitch noise (no vibrations), but in Ubuntu it just works perfectly, absolutely no noise.
It's all the same whether I'm running Windows 7 or Windows 8, or Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04!

Comment: In Ubuntu it doesn't matter if my hard disk is active or idle, but in Windows, it makes the noise only when it's idle!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably set to spin-down when the system is idle

[image]